# In MVC5 I am getting a cast error on my bootstrap bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm getting Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CallNode' to type 'Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.AstNodeList. on

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

This has to be something really stupid but I couldn't find it anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to render the bundle in a partial view?

Comment: It's the default _layouts.cshtml page. This was put in by the MVC creation wizard.

Comment: Was there ever an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Check the scripts in the bundle. There must be a error in the script. Most probably the below error must be present

Instead of

```
$("#myElement")
```

you might have typed

```
$("#
myElement")
```

Thanks,
R. Venkatesan